# Azure Blob Storage File Paths

Tags: ios, swift, azure-storage

I'm going to be using the Azure Storage REST API to create and retrieve images uploaded by users using my iOS app. I'd like a directory structure something like

container_name/user_Id/group_Id/item_Id/image.jpg

Each user can have multiple group_Ids and each item can have multiple images.

Is this even possible and if so, should each user have their own container or have them all under one container?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Azure Blob Storage doesn't really has directory structure in the server side. Instead, the structure is simply two level: container, blob.

However, there is a workaround: you can name your blobs with "virtual directory" prefix, just like `container_name/user_Id/group_Id/item_Id` in your example, and then list blobs under your container with prefix specified.

Answer (score 0):

> container_name/user_Id/group_Id/item_Id/image.jpg

As mentioned by @Zhaoxing Lu - Microsoft, By including path information in blob names, you can create a virtual directory structure you can organize and traverse as you would a traditional file system. The directory structure is virtual only--the only resources available in Blob storage are containers and blobs. However, the storage client library offers a CloudBlobDirectory object to refer to a virtual directory and simplify the process of working with blobs that are organized in this way

For example, consider the following set of block blobs in a container named photos:

```
photo1.jpg
2010/architecture/description.txt
2010/architecture/photo3.jpg
2010/architecture/photo4.jpg
2011/architecture/photo5.jpg
2011/architecture/photo6.jpg
2011/architecture/description.txt
2011/photo7.jpg
```

Full documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs)